# How to consume SQL Server stored procedures in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been told to consume a SQL Server stored procedure in PHP. Based on research I have written a script in PHP, but I don't know why it is showing me that the stored procedure execution failed. Please help me to identify what exactly I have been doing wrong please help me to identify my mistake. I am sharing SQL Server stored procedure with the code I have written in PHP.

```sql
USE [InteropDB]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Ins_OtherKRA_Modification]    Script Date: 25-08-2022 11:34:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


-- =============================================
-- Author:      <jagruti    >
-- Create date: <08062022,>
-- Description: <Other_KRAmodification record insert>
--EXEC interopDB..Ins_OtherKRA_Modification '\\192.168.4.107\kratocvl\4.107\05072022.txt'
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Ins_OtherKRA_Modification]
        @filepath VARCHAR (100)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    --declare @filepath VARCHAR (100) = '\\192.168.4.107\kratocvl\4.107\28062022.txt'

    --Removing Dupilcate from imod
    SELECT IMOD_KYC_PANNO PAN,imod_kyc_title POSCODE,imod_kyc_cm_id CMID,MAX(IMOD_ID) IMODID,COUNT(1) AS CNT
    INTO #IMOD_DUPLICATE
    FROM interop_modified_kyc_details WHERE imod_kyc_status = '01'
    GROUP BY IMOD_KYC_PANNO,imod_kyc_title,imod_kyc_cm_id
    HAVing count(1) > 1

    select * from #imod_duplicate

    UPDATE IMOD
    SET IMOD_KYC_STATUS = '99',
    IMOD_KYC_COMMENTS = IMOD_KYC_COMMENTS + ' - DUPLICATE'
    FROM interop_modified_kyc_details IMOD
    JOIN #IMOD_DUPLICATE ON PAN = imod_kyc_panno AND POSCODE = imod_kyc_title AND CMID = imod_kyc_cm_id
    AND imod_kyc_status = '01'
    AND IMODID <> imod_id 

    DROP TABLE #IMOD_DUPLICATE

    DECLARE @@DATE DATETIME = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @test varchar(2000) = ''
    DECLARE @@FILE_LOCATION AS VARCHAR(100)  
    SELECT @@FILE_LOCATION  =  replace(gbl_interop_filepath,'\','/') from kycdb..global_master

    CREATE TABLE #IARPANNO (
        IARPAN VARCHAR(10),
        IARPOS VARCHAR(20),
        IARFILENAME VARCHAR(50),
        IARFOLDERNO VARCHAR(5)
        )

    CREATE TABLE #OTHERKRA_BACKOFFICE_IMAGE (
        OBIPAN VARCHAR(10),
        OBIPOS VARCHAR(20),
        OBIFILENAME VARCHAR(50),
        OBIFOLDERNO VARCHAR(5),
        OBIONBEHALFPOS VARCHAR(20),
        OBIIMODID BIGINT,
        OBIKYCID BIGINT,
        OBIKRACODE VARCHAR(10),
        OBIFLAG BIGINT )

    SET @test = N'BULK INSERT #IARPANNO FROM ''' + 
                @filepath + 
                N''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'
    exec(@test)

    INSERT INTO #OTHERKRA_BACKOFFICE_IMAGE
    SELECT IARPAN,IARPOS,IARFILENAME,IARFOLDERNO,'',0,0,'',0
    FROM #IARPANNO
    
    UPDATE OBI
    SET OBIFLAG = 1,
        OBIKYCID = imod_kyc_id,
        OBIIMODID = imod_id,
        OBIKRACODE = imod_desc_kra
    FROM INTEROP_AUTOMODIFY_RAISED (nolock) 
    JOIN kycdb..company_master cmid (nolock) on cmid.cm_id = IAR_CM_ID
    JOIN #OTHERKRA_BACKOFFICE_IMAGE OBI ON OBIPAN = IAR_PANNO AND OBIPOS = cmid.CM_CODE
    join kycdb..company_master cmcode (nolock) on cmcode.CM_CODE = IAR_POSCODE
    JOIN INTEROP_MODIFIED_KYC_DETAILS (nolock) ON IMOD_ID = IAR_IMOD_ID AND IMOD_KYC_PANNO = IAR_PANNO AND IMOD_KYC_STATUS = '01'
    AND imod_kyc_comments = 'Interop Auto Modification'
    AND IMOD_KYC_TITLE = cmcode.CM_CODE
    and imod_kyc_cm_id = cmid.CM_ID
     where IAR_FETCH_FLAG = 'Y' AND  IAR_IMG_FLAG <> 'Y'

    --select * from #OTHERKRA_BACKOFFICE_IMAGE WHERE OBIFLAG = 0
    --return

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
    INSERT INTO INTEROP_MODIFIED_KYC_IMAGES
    SELECT OBIIMODID, OBIKYCID,OBIPAN, OBIFILENAME+ '.ZIP', @@FILE_LOCATION+OBIFOLDERNO+'/',OBIFILENAME + '.ZIP', 1,@@DATE
    FROM #OTHERKRA_BACKOFFICE_IMAGE
    where OBIFLAG = 1

    UPDATE IAR 
    SET IAR_IMG_FLAG = 'Y',
    IAR_IMG_ID = IMKI_ID,
    IAR_MODIFYDT = @@DATE
    FROM INTEROP_AUTOMODIFY_RAISED IAR (NOLOCK)
    JOIN #OTHERKRA_BACKOFFICE_IMAGE (NOLOCK) ON  OBIPAN = IAR_PANNO AND OBIIMODID = IAR_IMOD_ID AND OBIFLAG = 1
    JOIN INTEROP_MODIFIED_KYC_IMAGES (NOLOCK) ON IMKI_MOD_ID = OBIIMODID


    INSERT INTO OTHERKRA_BACKOFFICE_IMAGE
    SELECT  OBIPAN,
            OBIPOS,
            OBIFILENAME,
            OBIFOLDERNO,
            @@DATE,
            OBIONBEHALFPOS,
            OBIFLAG
    FROM    #OTHERKRA_BACKOFFICE_IMAGE

    SELECT  OBIKRACODE,count(*) 
    FROM    #OTHERKRA_BACKOFFICE_IMAGE
    group by OBIKRACODE
    order by OBIKRACODE

    SELECT  OBIPAN,OBIPOS,CASE WHEN OBIFLAG = 1 THEN 'SUCCESS' ELSE 'NOT PROCESSED' END AS STATUSRESPONSE
    FROM    #OTHERKRA_BACKOFFICE_IMAGE

    DROP TABLE #IARPANNO
    DROP TABLE #OTHERKRA_BACKOFFICE_IMAGE

END


GO
```

Above is my SQL Server stored procedure as per my knowledge for executing stored procedure in PHP one need to EXEC stored procedure name with it's parameters correct me if I am wrong.

```php
<?php
$serverName = "192.168.22.68";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"testkycdb", "UID"=>"uatkrasqluser", "PWD"=>"CV!u@t2018");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);
if($conn){
    echo "Connection Success<br/>";
}else{
    echo "Connection could not be established .<br/>";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$procedure_params = array(
array(&$myparams['FILE_LOCATION'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)
);


$sql = "EXEC Ins_OtherKRA_Modification  @FILE_LOCATION= ?";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $procedure_params);

if( !$stmt ) {
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo print_r($row, true);
}

if($row==0){
    echo "stored procedure execution  failed";
}

else{
    echo "stored procedure execution success";
}



sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);


?>
'''

Error message 
stored procedure execution failed
```

Comment: Please don't write sentences all in upper case. All upper case is considering SCREAMING. It also makes the text harder for us to read.

Comment: Where does `$myparams` come from? I don't see it being defined anywhere?

Comment: in the PHP you call the procedure with 3 parameters, but in the sql I see the procedure has only one parameter

Comment: @GuidoG I am not much aware about this. but I though whatever is decalre using @ is known as parameters

Comment: @M.Eriksson $myparams I am defining my parameter

Comment: `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Ins_OtherKRA_Modification]
        @filepath VARCHAR (100)
AS` clearly shows the procedure has only one parameter, named FilePath

Comment: @ESHA You have `EXEC Ins_OtherKRA_Modification @DATE = ?, @test= ?, @FILE_LOCATION= ?` in your PHP, so you are defining you want to pass the *parameters* `@DATE`, `@test` and `@FILE_LOCATION` to the procedure. The procedure you define above, however, is defined as `[dbo].[Ins_OtherKRA_Modification] @filepath VARCHAR (100)` It doesn't have *any* of the parameters you defined in your PHP, and the only one it *does* have is called `@filepath`

Comment: And `$sql = "EXEC Ins_OtherKRA_Modification @DATE = ?, @test= ?, @FILE_LOCATION= ?";` here you call it with 3 parameters

Comment: @GuidoG I am getting your point  I thought rest 2 are also parameter ... perhaps I should call my stored procedure with only one parameter

Comment: not perhaps, but definitly, or add 2 parameters to the procedure, it is up to you we don't know what you need

Comment: @GuidoG I modified my code and used one parameter Than too I don't know why it is giving error message of stored procedure was not executed

Comment: Then edit your question and show us the modified code, and the exact complete error message

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). You have picked up many bad tsql habits - a very different question but one you need to address. Does the stored procedure work correctly when you run it directly from SSMS using the same identity as your application?

Comment: You still don't show us the complete and exact error message

Comment: @SMor Stored procedure was not written by me .. It was written by my colleague. and just for learning process I want to know What's harm in splattering code with nolock

Comment: Have you read the article in the link of @SMor 's comment ?

Comment: @GuidoG There is no option of sharing screen-shot over here . Otherwise I would have done the same ... I am getting two response in my output which is Connection Success and
stored procedure execution failed that too i have written in my program  Connection Success is result that my php and sql server are connected my stored-procedure is failing

Comment: @GuidoG just now I readed that article

Comment: you can copy / paste the error in the question, not ?

Comment: Instead of `echo "stored procedure execution  failed";` you should do `echo print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);` that will tell you the exact error

Comment: Some things I will note: `SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT` should be `SQLSRV_PARAM_IN`. Do not use `NOLOCK` or `READ UNCOMMITTED` especially with modification queries. The temp tables are probably not necessary, but you should probably check at the top if they exist before blindly creating them. You do not have proper error handling in PHP, you should be using `finally` blocks to close and dispose the statement and connection objects.

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for your suggestions . I really appreciate it